# Git alias with shell variable expansions

Tags: git, shell

I'd like to use a shell variable expansion inside of a git alias to strip a prefix of a branch. Unfortunately when I use the "standard" alias, variable expansion is not done:

```
publish = push -u origin ${$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)##refs/heads/}
```

This is trying to actually push a branch called "${$(git". But if I change the alias to:

```
publish = "!git push -u origin ${$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)##refs/heads/}"
```

it's run via sh and fails to do the substitution I want. Is there some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
!git push -u origin ${$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)##refs/heads/}
```

to

```
!git push -u origin `git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e "s#^refs/heads/##"`
```

This uses `sh` backticks to execute commands and `sed` to do the regular expression substitution.

Comment: @viraptor mmmm if that's the solution, I'd seriously consider just delegating to a bash script proper and not bother with any such archaics :) In a bash script, there will be no surprises and unlimited options.

Answer (score 1):

Low-level explanation: The `${xxx}` syntax always requires a **variable name** for xxx. It does not substitute an arbitrary string. To use ##, one would have to: `x=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD); echo ${x##refs/heads/};`

Comment: True for bash, but zsh does support it as the OP wrote it.