# Is there a way to have --set-upstream automatically specified when doing git push?

Tags: git

Every time I create a branch and push it, this happens:

$ git push
fatal: The current branch foo has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

```
git push --set-upstream origin foo

$ git push --set-upstream origin foo
```

Given I am on branch foo, the whole '--set-upstream origin foo' feels like redundant typing (or rather, copy-pasting).

Is there a way I can set a config option so that 'git push' while on a branch that has no upstream automatically sets the upstream branch name to match the local branchname?

Comment: I like [`thefuck`](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck)

Comment: Not the droids you're looking for, but you can replace `--set-upstream` with `-u` to save a few characters.

Answer (score 3):

The following alias in your gitconfig will work.  The hard work of getting the alias right is due to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310435/git-alias-with-shell-variable-expansions) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658283/git-bad-config-when-piping-commands), but they never say in the question or answer what they are trying to do.

```
    publish = !git push -u origin `git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e "s#^refs/heads/##"`
```

or

```
    publish = !git push -u origin `git branch | grep \\* | cut -d ' ' -f2`
```

Then a simple `git publish` does what you want.

Answer (score -1):

**Simple, create tracking branches**

You should either use complete `git push origin <remote_branch>` notation or set up a tracking branch.

```
git branch --track branch-name origin/branch-name
git branch --set-upstream-to <remote-branch> # for existing branches
```

Now you can just `git push` and it would work.