# Nest backticks inside a git command alias

Tags: git, backticks, command-substitution, git-alias

I'm attempting to make a git alias to show all commits since the last tag. I'm basing it of this SO answer that I've used a lot in the past.

Currently, I'm trying this with a `git config --global alias.*` command like so:

```
git config --global alias.summary 'log `git describe --tags --abbrev=0`..HEAD --oneline'
```

This registers a new 'command' named 'summary' that would render out all the commit messages since the last tag.

However, when I run `git summary`, git throws out this error message:

> fatal: ambiguous argument '`git': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
>
> Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
>
> 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

To me, this looks like the inner command `git describe --tags --abbrev=0` that are nested inside the backticks do not evaluate correctly.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the benefit of using $() instead of backticks in shell scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449778/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-instead-of-backticks-in-shell-scripts)

Comment: Try `$(....)` in place of backticks. They nest.

Comment: Using `$()` when generating the alias results in the latest tag (if I'm in a repo) being embedded into the alias command; the desired behaviour is I can run `git summary` in any repository and it would list out all commits since the last tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out that you need to use the **bang**/`!` operator to flag to git that the alias should execute in the shell.

On a side note, replacing `git describe --tags --abbrev=0` with `$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)`, causes the command to execute before it is placed into the [alias] section of the config file. This results in an alias command with the latest tag version being baked into the alias instead it dynamically finding the latest git tag.

IE: If a repository had the tags `1.1.0` and `2.0.0` and I attempted to add the alias a few commits on from `2.0.0`, it would generate the following alias command:

```
'!git log 2.0.0..HEAD --oneline;'
```

This means `2.0.0` is now fixed as the tag to check against rather than dynamically finding the latest tag for the repository in question.

So, to fix my initial git alias, I needed to add **`!git`** to the start of the alias command:

```
git config --global alias.summary '!git log `git describe --tags --abbrev=0`..HEAD --oneline;'
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: my original suggestion still holds, but check this out too:
[Git alias with shell variable expansions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310435/git-alias-with-shell-variable-expansions)

I would suggest creating this as a bash function instead. I don't think Git is going to parse this correctly, and the net effect will be the same. You can add this to `~/.bashrc` to have it automatically configured on shell startup.

```
gitsummary() {
    git log `git describe --tags --abbrev=0`..HEAD --oneline
}
```

You can execute bash functions as if they were standard apps, so like this

```
cd /my/git/dir
gitsummary
```

Comment: Using `$(...)` instead of backticks for command substitution obviates the need to define a shell function.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, while not exactly what I was after (as I'd prefer to just execute the command like it was a native git operation rather than a bash function) this did put me on the right path.